# How to add/remove ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have an osmdroid map. I an going to add a layer on it, its not an Overlay, its a layer. There is no problem when I m adding layer but when I have try to remove the layer. There is an Exception :

> ***The layer is not a sub-layer of the current map.***

The code for adding and removing the layer is :

if(Layer_List_Adapter.toggle_status==true)
                {

```
                    Log.i("ADDING LAYER... :", "Adding...");
                    mapView.addLayer(dmsl);
                    Log.i("Layers ::", ""+mapView.getLayers());
                    layer_added_falg=true;

            }

            else if(Layer_List_Adapter.toggle_status==false)
            {

                Log.i("A", "A");

                    if(layer_added_falg==true)
                    {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.i("REMOVING LAYER... :", "Removing...");
                        Log.i("Layers ::", ""+mapView.getLayers());
                        mapView.removeLayer(mapView.getLayerByID(layerId));
                        mapView.refreshDrawableState();
                        layer_added_falg=false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception

                        Log.e("ERROR :", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    }

                    else
                    {

                    }

            }
```